# How to let user change font size and color

Tags: java, android

I would like to let the user select font color and size inside app.

I have made a working solution to this, but this code is not easily scalable. For example if I would also want to let the user select spacing, then I would have to make multiple copy-paste `FontStyle_Small_Black_SpacingSmall, FontStyle_Small_Black_SpacingMedium, FontStyle_Small_Black_SpacingLarge, FontStyle_Small_Red_SpacingSmall, FontStyle_Small_Red_SpacingMedium` etc.

This can't be the best way of achieving this functionality, so that's why I'm asking for help.

Here is all the base code:

```
// Enum FontStyle
public enum FontStyle {
    SmallBlack(R.style.FontStyle_Small_Black, "SmallBlack"),
    SmallRed(R.style.FontStyle_Small_Red, "SmallRed"),
    SmallGreen(R.style.FontStyle_Small_Green, "SmallGreen"),
    SmallBlue(R.style.FontStyle_Small_Blue, "SmallBlue"),
    MediumBlack(R.style.FontStyle_Medium_Black, "MediumBlack"),
    MediumRed(R.style.FontStyle_Medium_Red, "MediumRed"),
    MediumGreen(R.style.FontStyle_Medium_Green, "MediumGreen"),
    MediumBlue(R.style.FontStyle_Medium_Blue, "MediumBlue"),
    LargeBlack(R.style.FontStyle_Large_Black, "LargeBlack"),
    LargeRed(R.style.FontStyle_Large_Red, "LargeRed"),
    LargeGreen(R.style.FontStyle_Large_Green, "LargeGreen"),
    LargeBlue(R.style.FontStyle_Large_Blue, "LargeBlue");

    private int resId;
    private String title;

    public int getResId() {
        return resId;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    FontStyle(int resId, String title) {
        this.resId = resId;
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

```
// attrs.xml
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="FontStyle">
        <attr name="font_small" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_medium" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_large" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_xlarge" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="font_color" format="color" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

```
// styles.xml
<resources>
    <style name="FontStyle">
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Small">
        <item name="font_small">14dp</item>
        <item name="font_medium">16dp</item>
        <item name="font_large">18dp</item>
        <item name="font_xlarge">20dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Medium">
        <item name="font_small">18dp</item>
        <item name="font_medium">20dp</item>
        <item name="font_large">22dp</item>
        <item name="font_xlarge">24dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Large">
        <item name="font_small">22dp</item>
        <item name="font_medium">24dp</item>
        <item name="font_large">26dp</item>
        <item name="font_xlarge">28dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Small.Black">
        <item name="font_color">#000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Small.Red">
        <item name="font_color">#F00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Small.Green">
        <item name="font_color">#0F0</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Small.Blue">
        <item name="font_color">#00F</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Medium.Black">
        <item name="font_color">#000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Medium.Red">
        <item name="font_color">#F00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Medium.Green">
        <item name="font_color">#0F0</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Medium.Blue">
        <item name="font_color">#00F</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Large.Black">
        <item name="font_color">#000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Large.Red">
        <item name="font_color">#F00</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Large.Green">
        <item name="font_color">#0F0</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FontStyle.Large.Blue">
        <item name="font_color">#00F</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

```
// I use getTheme() in every Activity I have
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // GlobalPrefs is my class which is used to load saved style from preferences    
    getTheme().applyStyle(GlobalPrefs.getFontStyle().getResId(), true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

```
// Usage in xml
<TextView
    android:textSize="?attr/font_medium"
    android:textColor="?attr/font_color"/>
```

```
// Settings Activity used for user to change font style
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FontStyle[][] styles = new FontStyle[][]{
            {FontStyle.SmallBlack, FontStyle.SmallRed, FontStyle.SmallGreen, FontStyle.SmallBlue},
            {FontStyle.MediumBlack, FontStyle.MediumRed, FontStyle.MediumGreen, FontStyle.MediumBlue},
            {FontStyle.LargeBlack, FontStyle.LargeRed, FontStyle.LargeGreen, FontStyle.LargeBlue}
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Load font theme
        getTheme().applyStyle(GlobalPrefs.getFontStyle().getResId(), true);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        setupFontSize();
        setupFontColor();
    }

    private void setupFontSize() {
        // Here I use Spinner to get font size
    }

    private void setupFontColor() {
        // Here I use Spinner to get font color
    }

    private void updateFontStyle() {
        int size = GlobalPrefs.getFontSizePos();
        int color = GlobalPrefs.getFontColorPos();
        GlobalPrefs.setFontStyle(styles[size][color]);

        // Restart activity to apply changes to xml views
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }
}
```

I can share more code if anyone wants to, but this should be enough the get the idea.

Comment: You may want to create a fiddle

Comment: @A.Abramov Sorry, I am unfamiliar with the term "fiddle". Do you mean that I should use Fiddler or what?

Comment: Nope, I mean you should create a working example that demonstrates your issue, since getting through your code isnt too simple. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/